# Invalid register Must be between v0 and v15, inclusive

Tags: android, bytecode, smali, apktool

I had below smali code that worked well with no error.I have add an statement after the move-result to log `v18` at logcat, but now I have an error

```
    invoke-static {v9}, Lcom/mycompany/myapp/MyClass1;->getMystring((Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
    move-result-object v18
    #I added below line 
    invoke-static {v18}, Lcom/mycompany/myapp/MyClass2;->logMessage(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

but I have error now:

```
    Invalid register: v18. Must be between v0 and v15, inclusive
```

What should I use instead of v18 to remove the error in the last line

Answer (score 1):

`invoke-static` is one of the instructions that can address only the first 16 [registers](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/wiki/Registers) (`v0` to `v15` as said in the error message). There are a few options, all of them involve finding a register that you can use for yourself.

1. Replace `v18` in `move-result-object` with another register. You might need to update its uses in other places accordingly.
2. Copy value from `v18` into another register using `move-object vX, v18` where `vX` is the new register and use `invoke-static` with `vX`.
3. If you can't find a register that would be safe to override, you can temporary copy it to a register with a higher index using `move-object/16 vYY, vX` and then restore it with `move-object/from16 vX, vYY`. You'll need to [increase the number of registers the function uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074422/increase-local-registers-in-smali-and-use-new-register).

Note that registers aren't shared between methods, so you need to care only about preserving the behavior of the current method.